# How can I get a date box to show when the database uses global themes?

Tags: themes, xpages

I have an application that I downloaded from OpenNTF.  It uses some global stylesheets.

[stylesheets list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWRme.png)

One of these is preventing my date field from showing in Chrome or I.E., it shows fine in Firefox.  I can't remove the stylesheets, because they support other features of the application.

I created a simple xpage with only the date field on it for testing.  Since the field shows fine in another database, I know that the culprit must be one of the stylesheets.

If I simply choose to disableTheme, then the box will show, but without a date picker (in all browsers).  Is there a way for me to use a date field with a date picker that works in all browsers - even with all these global stylesheets?

Comment: You have to check the difference in css applied  to this date fields in Chrome and FF and override it in your own css file. First check the `float` property.

Comment: Thank you for the direction... that's what worked - I copied in a local theme and created an extend theme that added the custom theme in the db.  Then I used that extended theme as my new app theme.  It works!